# Buy 3 discount 1

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, promotions

I have some promo rule, (buy x) y free ... but just apply when the quantity of the "same" product are 3, but if i add 3 items  in total but (2 items a and 1 item b) the total are 3, but dont discount for the total amount.

[image: promo configuration]
[image: promo not apply with 3 total items]
[image: product apply]

Answer (score 0):

check this the answer here [Click here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16053/buy-x-product-and-get-y-another-product-free-of-same-category.)

You should create custom module or install 3th party module, by default Magento doesn't support. As alternative you can create a fixed amount discount and discount to be the price of the products in your case (19.99$).